# Disable reusing cell in some cases

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a strange situation, in some cases I want to disable cell reusable "feature" in the cell. If some condition met I dont' wan't reuse that cell.

What is the beautiful method for this?(I know the purpose of the reuseIdentifier, but I have some strange dependency so, no I want from this cell to become none reusable.)

I can't modify the reuseIdentifier because it is a read only property.
I can override the getter "- (NSString *)reuseIdentifier", but I don't like this idea.

Any other suggestion for this problem?

Comment: If you need to stop reusing cells, then your design is faulty. You can certainly achieve the same thing with a proper design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that my design is not good, but at now I have no other choices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to avoid reusing a cell, something is wrong either with your code or the design: the mechanism of reusing cells is very flexible, you should be able to adjust it to your needs.

However, the effect that you want is relatively easy to achieve: if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns a cell that you do not want to reuse, do not return that cell from your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Create a new cell in its place, or dequeue another cell.

Comment: I believe OP has a problem with the content of a cell being lost if it is reused. While you're still right that this sounds like bad design, your approach does not avoid that problem. Instead, the condition should be checked before dequeueing and a new cell should be created (via alloc-init, using a different reuse-identifier) or dequeued (using a different reuse-identifier) instead.

Comment: @patric.schenke I do not have enough info about the specifics of the OP's problem, but I assumed that the decision to not reuse a cell cannot be made without looking at that cell. If the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method has enough info to decide this before dequeueing a cell, it could definitely do that.